# Query millions of Rows | PostgreSQL |

Tags: java

I'm querying through millions of rows of data, and the tomcat in the server just drops. The fix I found was to fetch 1000 rows of data from the database at a time so as not to load the tomcat in the server.
I am aware of setFetchSize() method which I am using and setAutoCommit() is set to false.

However, it doesn't seem to be working.

Perhaps, you can help me with more ideas to get that many rows of data without slowing down the performance?

Comment: Why does this question smell of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me?

Comment: Retrieving "millions of rows" is usually (but not always) not desirable. What are you trying to do exactly? What is your query? What are you doing with the returned rows?

Comment: @Bohemian The idea is to export it to a csv file, but when querying all that data it takes down the tomcat in the server. So instead I thought we could query smaller chunks of data and query that, and export it.

Comment: Databases have utilities that copy data to a file. You're doing this the hard way.

Comment: Use an operation solution for an operational function, so use a DB export utility. However, if java is the only way, rather than get rows in chunks, you can use a cursor to scroll through the rows 1 by 1, so the in-memory footprint is tiny and you can run just one query.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working" Please explain exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses guys! Especial thanks to @Bohemian for your follow up reply